# My swapfiles are 9.2GB in total in the file system while the actual reported is only 4.6gb. Why is that?

Tags: swap

I have a problem with the size of my swap memory. I tried to increase my swap memory following online guides and although I made it seems like I have messed up some steps. The end result now is that I see 3 swap files (swapfile=8.1GB, swapfile1=536.9MB, swapfile2=536.9MB) while the swap memory in the system monitor only shows 4.6GB.

Yesterday that I created the two new files swapfile1 and swapfile2 the system monitor was showing a total of 5.6GB swap memory.
Do you know how I can make the total 9.2GB be available?
This is the output of `free -h`:

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available Mem:          7.5Gi       3.3Gi       2.3Gi       560Mi       1.9Gi       3.4Gi Swap:         4.6Gi        33Mi       4.5Gi`

This command `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` gives me that:

`/swapfile                                    none            swap    sw              0       0`

Finally my swapiness is 60: This
`sysctl vm.swappiness` gives me this
`vm.swappiness = 60` 
[Image from my folders with the swapfiles and the system monitor here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDXJF.png)

Comment: What is the output of swapon --show?

Comment: @PonJar This is the output of swapon:                                                                                                               NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile   file     4.6G   0B       -2

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `ls -alh /swapfile*` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and I can make a recommendation. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your /etc/fstab file to the question. Was /swapfile 4.6G when you started? You might want to start again, swapoff all the existing files, delete them and create a single /swapfile of the size you are looking for. Here is a clear guide. https://itsfoss.com/create-swap-file-linux/

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /swapfile` ?

Comment: @heynnema I added those in the question. @PonJar I tried to see the contents of the `/etc/fstab` but I think I am a bit novice and couldn't find exactly how to do it in the command line :()! However the article was very good! I followed its last part that was talking about "Resizing swap space on Linux" and made it to resize and delete the additional files! First I tried the first part of the article about how to create the swapfile but the part I was failing was to make the changes permanent. This is where I was failing  in the first place as wel yesterday when my issue was raisedl.

Comment: It sounds like you may have fixed your own problem, but I put together an answer for you that shows the correct way to make a 4G /swapfile... which should be large enough for you.

Comment: For future reference you can view the contents of the fstab file with “cat /etc/fstab” This works for any file if you give it the right path. Glad you are sorted . @heynnema knows his stuff :)

Comment: @heynnema just did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may already have fixed the problem yourself, but just in case... here's how to create a 4G /swapfile... if you want larger /swapfile, change the 4096 (multiples of 1024)...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```